Why is my JetBrains Mono font sometimes not active and how can I fix it?
I use the JetBrains Mono font for VScode and it used to work perfectly every time, however now it can sometimes just not start and I have to reinstall it. I also noticed that it sometimes work if I close the entire window and then reopen it. This shouldn't be necessary since I have this in my settings.json file:
"editor.fontFamily": "JetBrains Mono",
"editor.fontWeight": "normal",
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
"editor.codeLensFontFamily": "JetBrains Mono",
"editor.fontVariations": true,

I have tried commenting out those lines, restarting VScode, un-commenting them, and then restarting VScode again but nothing seems to work (I have done every single thing I could think of).

are you missing single-quotes around the font family name? it has a space in it

I tried putting single quotes inside of the double quotes but it did not work
